# Making Vista shutdown less impatient

Tags: windows-vista, shutdown

On shutting down or restarting Windows Vista, it brings up the list of programs that are still running, and gives you the option of hard killing them immediately (thus potentially destroying data) or waiting for them to turn out the lights of their own accord. And this is as it should be.

Unfortunately, Vista doesn't actually keep this promise - within a couple of seconds, it goes ahead and kills everything anyway, regardless of what I do (thus potentially destroying data).

Is there a way to make it less impatient?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Adjust the `WaitToKillAppTimeout` value in Registry at `HKEY_CURRENT_USER\Control Panel\Desktop`. (It's in milliseconds.)

Comment: No such key on my machine, but a Google search suggests WaitToKillServiceTimeout is the equivalent on Vista, so I'm trying that instead.

Comment: @rwallace: It's a value, not a key (directory). And if it doesn't exist, try creating one (of type REG_SZ).